Question on Fourier series expression if $φ(x)$ can be expressed as a full Fourier series
Statement: Assume that $φ(x)$ can be expressed as a full Fourier series over $(−1, 1)$, then the series and $φ(x)$ take the same value at $x = 1$.
I think the above statement is true because Fourier sine series can be regarded as an expansion of any odd function, so if $φ(x)$ is odd, then the series is 0, and its 0 at 1 as well. If $φ(x)$ is even, then Fourier cos series can be regarded as an expansion, and the series will have same value at 1 as the series at 1. Just wanted to ask here and see if my answer and understanding is right.
